# Cant access image from Multer after having deployed to digital ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, digital-ocean, multer

Attempting to send an image to my express backend, store the image and run a tesseract process on the image file.

On localhost this process works perfectly. The image is stored, i can access the image file and i can process the image with tesseract.

On the deployed express server i can store the image but the results from the function is empty. Do i have to access the image file differently?

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage});

router.post('/api', upload.single('image'), async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    if (req.file.path) {
      const imageData = await processImage(req.file.path)
      return res.status(200).json('imageData');
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json(`error message: ${error.message}`);
  }
})
```

I have tried different paths to file without success in case the path has to be accessed differently on the deployed server. Or do i need to create a file type from path for tesseract to work? any help would be appreciated.

```
  const host = req.hostname;
  const filePath = req.protocol + "://" + host + '/' + req.file.path;
  const filePath2 = "http://**.***.***.**/var/www/app_name/_work/app_name-backend/" + req.file.path;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Not sure how to debug this once i deploy. req.body.path gives me the correct file name similar to localhost but the tesseract function returns an empty string. Therefore I assume its not accessing the image correctly. trying to access the image through a path is also tricky since unlike req.body.path it becomes a string and not a file type.